# ActionBar no Android Studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio, actionbar

Eu atualizei meu Android Studio para a versão 1.4 e estou tendo problemas para implementar o ActionBar numa `activity`.
O aplicativo executa a validação dos dados de um usuário através do `MainActivity` e depois direciona o usuário para a segunda `activity`(`WelcomeActivity`). Estou tentando criar um "`up navigation` "através do código`getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`mas quando eu executo o aplicativo, ele fecha no momento que vai passar de uma activity para outra. Se eu remover a informação da `actionbar` mencionado acima, o aplicativo funciona normalmente.
Também tentei retirar as informações referentes a `toolbar` que existe nas activities mas não funcionou.

```
//        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package br.com.luizugliano.actionbar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}

public void onClickBtBuscar(View view){
    EditText etNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNome);
    EditText etCPF = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCPF);
    String nome = etNome.getText().toString();
    String cpf = etCPF.getText().toString();
    if("luiz".equals(nome) && "123456789".equals(cpf)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),WelcomeActivity.class);
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("nome", "Luiz");
        intent.putExtras(params);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        alert("Usuário não encontrado, faça seu cadastro");
    }
}

private Context getContext(){
    return this;
}

private void alert(String s){
    Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

**WelcomeActivity.java**

```
package br.com.luizugliano.actionbar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();
    String nome = args.getString("nome");

    //Atualizando o texto do TextView com uma mensagem de boas vindas
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(nome + ", seja bem-vindo.");

    //Adiciona o botão de navegação da action bar
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        //O método finish encerrará essa activity
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="br.com.luizugliano.actionbar" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

**content_welcome.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_welcome"
tools:context="br.com.luizugliano.activity.WelcomeActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />
```

**activity_welcome.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="br.com.luizugliano.actionbar.WelcomeActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_welcome" />

<!--<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"-->
    <!--android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />-->
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

**logcat crash log**

> 10-15 00:25:42.457 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar-2/lib/x86
>   10-15 00:25:42.680 4456-4472/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
>   10-15 00:25:42.683 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xad70ddb0, tid 4456
>   10-15 00:25:42.735 4456-4472/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xad70dfb0, tid 4472
>   10-15 00:25:42.757 4456-4472/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>   10-15 00:25:42.854 4456-4472/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>   10-15 00:25:42.854 4456-4472/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabfa99e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime: Process: br.com.luizugliano.actionbar, PID: 4456
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.luizugliano.actionbar/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar.WelcomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at br.com.luizugliano.actionbar.WelcomeActivity.onCreate(WelcomeActivity.java:25)
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>   10-15 00:26:02.266 4456-4456/br.com.luizugliano.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O certo nesse caso, usando a `AppCompatActivity` é usar o método `getSupportActionBar`.

Se caso não usasse a biblioteca de suporte, poderia usar normalmente o `getActionBar`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Estava vendo o motivo da exceção através do logcat e está falando que minha actionBar está nula-`br.com.luizugliano.actionbar.WelcomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference 10-15`. Tentei retirar a biblioteca `AppCompactActivity` fazendo um extend de outra classe que criei pra controlar o ciclo de vida do app mas mesmo assim está dando erro ao mudar de uma activity para outra. Você consegue me ajudar mostrando como sua sugestão ficaria no meu codig

Comment: Exato, você setou a `supportActionBar` e está usando a `ActionBar` normal. Acredito que não é a mesma coisa.

Comment: Boa! Tentei alterar o código com as sugestões que você deu inicialmente mas continua dando problema. Você conseguiria me mandar sua sugestão de acordo com o código que postei?

Comment: Luiz, eu fiz a sugestão já olhando seu código xD Mas poderia atualizar a pergunta com as mudanças e o novo stacktrace do erro?

Comment: Na verdade eu alterei a chamada da biblioteca de suporte da classe. Alterei de `public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {` para `public class WelcomeActivity extends LifeCycleActivity {`, que é minha outra classe que apenas trata as etapas do ciclo de vida. Além disso, removi as condições abaixo referentes a `toolbar` - `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`. O erro retornado foi o mesmo. Achei estranho o `Manifest` ter atualizado minha classe com a informação `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"`. =[

Comment: Mas no caso, ainda precisa chamar o `getSupportActionBar`, passando o `Toolbar`, porque ao usar o tema com sufixo `NoActionBar`, você é obrigado a configurar o seu `Toolbar` como `ActionBar` caso queria usar a mesma. De resto acredito que esteja correto. Está chamando o `setSupportActionBar` na superclasse antes do `get`?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30331/discussion-between-luiz-henrique-ugliano-and-wakim).

Answer (score 2):

Caso alguém ainda esteja com esse problema que é muito comum, existem várias formas para utilizar a "ActionBar".
Vou falar uma maneira.

1. Para quem utiliza o Android Studio mais atual: Abra o arquivo AndroidManifest.xml

Você terá algo parecido com o código abaixo:

`<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"`

Remova a linha **android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"**.

2. Caso você tenha criado uma Activity pelo Wizard e ela criou a Toolbar, conforme o código abaixo:

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
   fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                   .setAction("Action", null).show();
       }
   });
   ```

   }

**Remova essas linhas.**

> Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
>
> setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
>
> FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
>
> fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

3. Faça essa importação, se possível manual.

`import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;`

4. Utilize as *ActionBars* da seguinte forma

> `ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();`

Dessa forma sua ActionBar vai funcionar, mas vale lembrar que (sinceramente não sei todas, mas a maioria das) funções da classe ActionBar está obsleta.

Espero ter ajudado. Sou novato em programação Android. Tive esses problemas também. Cada vez fazia de uma forma diferente e funcionava, mas dessa forma que passei acima me pareceu mais garantida.
Abraços.

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido alterando `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` para `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`